# How to detect that browser has deprecated XmlHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, compatibility

Recently, I have noticed this error in my Chr***m-related browser's console:

[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check h****://***.****.******.***/.

How can I anticipate that a browser will do this and create a workaround for what sounds like intended to become an API which can no longer be used?

I'm intending to maintain compatibility with older browsers indefinitely, so removing this behavior is not something I can remove outright, but I can perhaps feature-check around it?

Comment: all evergreen browsers have deprecated synchronous XmlHttpRequest - all browsers are capable of asynchronous XmlHttpRequest - so, write your code properly and compatibility is assured

Comment: @Bravo Thank you for responding with your suggestion. However, I stated clearly in my question that I intend to maintain compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: yes, correct, I can read and understand what I have read, thank you for uncorrecting me. what I said WONT break compatibility with internet explorer - I did say that **ALL** browsers are capable of asynchronous XMLHttpRequest - therefore, the solution is to write **your** code to NOT use synchronous XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something, @Bravo, but to me, "async" means either using async/await or promises, which is certainly not supported by browsers released before those features became a thing in JavaScript. Is there another way, which would be supported by e.g. pre-promises C****e or F*****x?

Comment: `"async" means either using async/await or promises,` ... XMLHttpRequest predates promises and async/await by 20 years ... so, no, it has nothing to do with promises - it has to do with how the request is made ... asynchronously or synchronously [read some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open#async)